# How to convert a string to uint64_t?

Tags: c++

This differs from other questions (Not a duplicate) Because I use actual characters in the string and not just numbers, with atoi and stoi and stoll I cant do that because it is invalid

so far I tried

```
    std::string k = "MyString";
    uint64_t test = (uint64_t)reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&k);
    printf("%hu \n", test);
```

But it keeps returning random values every time I start the program. Any ideas? Sorry I'm new a bit

its supposed to return 5582584972703264359

Comment: Why do you think that should return `5582584972703264359`

Comment: 5582584972703264359 is the decimal equivalent of the large hex number you would get you if appended all the ASCII values for those characters together.

Comment: That might answer "Why 5582584972703264359?", but not "why do you think that should return 5582584972703264359?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
uint64_t stringToUint(std::string k)
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    for (auto const& j : k)
    {
        r <<= 8;
        r |= j;
    }
    return r;
}
```

[See it live](https://onlinegdb.com/SyDBK2--P)

Let's look at your code:

```
uint64_t test = (uint64_t)reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&k);
```

This says to pretend a `uint64_t` is stored where the `std::string` is in memory. But no law says that what's stored where the `std::string` is in memory has to be the contents of the string itself. In fact, most likely what will be stored there is the *address* of the string and its length.

Why? Because a `std::string` can store 4 bytes one minute and then 1,000 bytes the next minute. But an object itself can't move in memory just because you changed its contents. So some level of indirection is often needed.

**CAUTION**: This isn't a particularly natural or logical thing to do. And the use case wasn't explained. So I just wrote code that produced the requested result without doing anything strange or arbitrary. It may or may not do what is expected for shorter strings, longer strings, or really any different strings because I have no idea what the expected behavior is for any other string.

Comment: Isn't `j` in `r |= j;` promoted to `int` to do the calculation?  If so, and `char` is signed and one of the values in the string is negative, it'll be sign extended?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It produces the results the OP asked for. And the OP isn't shy about UB. And we don't really have a problem specification beyond producing the requested result. So, ... *shrug*

Comment: Of course, the easiest way to produce "the expected result" is simply `return 5582584972703264359ULL;`. But that's a bit too cynical...